# flipbook through frames using frames per second timer

Tags: c#

Below is the code I created in attempt to make a timeline controlled by a play/stop button. I use the Timer from the Toolbox to increment time as I progress the timeline using the framesPerSecond. I feel that the timer seems to be a bit in accurate. I was wondering if any had any suggested improvements on controlling the time more accurately? I'm new to c# so bear with me on the coding. If it helps this code is for a larger project which I want to create, and this would be the control for the timeline which will eventually swap through images like a slideshow.
Thanks

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace timelineControls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Every time timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        }

        private void cbPlayStop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Flipbook();
        }

        private void numFps_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Flipbook();
        }

        public void Flipbook()
        {
            bool result = cbPlayStop.Checked;
            if (result)
            {
                cbPlayStop.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                cbPlayStop.Text = "Stop";

                // increment the counter at a speed of (X) per second
                float framerate = (float)1.0 / (float)numFps.Value;

                // Timer will tick every 1 seconds (1000 milliseconds)
                timer1.Interval = (int)((float)1000 * framerate);
                timer1.Enabled = true; // pauses/unpauses
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                cbPlayStop.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                cbPlayStop.Text = "Play";

                // stop timer from counting
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

        private int curTime = 0;

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Tick");                    // Alert the user
            int hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int minutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            int seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
            int milSeconds = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

            string timeString = hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds + " : " + milSeconds;


            bool loopEnabled = cbLoop.Checked;
            curTime += 1;
            if (loopEnabled)
            {
                if (curTime > pBarTime.Maximum)
                {
                    curTime = pBarTime.Minimum;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (curTime > pBarTime.Maximum)
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    curTime = pBarTime.Maximum;
                }
            }


            pBarTime.Value = curTime;
            label2.Text = timeString;
            lbCurTime.Text = curTime.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your question here?

Comment: "Frames per second" of what?

Comment: Timer isn't really well suited for precision timing, much less so for such small time spans. But to point you to the right solution, we need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: alright. ill reword it and add more code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new Tick event every time you call `FlipBook`, so yes, it's running multiple times.

Move that declaration to the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}
```

In regards to the Timer's capabilities, see [MSDN Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

Comment: you mention using this 'Timer class in the System.Timers namespace' I'm not quite sure how to implement that. Do you know of any good tutorials or examples?

Comment: @JokerMartini See [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Comment: I've made an attempt to update the code above in order to make the more accurate multithreaded counter. I keep getting an odd error when I try to increment my curTime variable. not sure why it's doing that. Like to know your thoughts.

Comment: @JokerMartini You keep adding the event handlers in the wrong place.  You seem to have missed the first part of my answer.

Comment: The tutorial i followed said to put it in the button. so i did as it said.

Comment: @JokerMartini You didn't put it in the button.  You put in the FlipBook method, which you call from multiple places.  It belongs in the constructor.

Comment: I corrected the placement of the code. Why does it still return this error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @JokerMartini Well, you picked System.Timers.Timer, which is: `The .NET Framework documentation refers to the System.Timers.Timer class as a server-based timer that was designed and optimized for use in multithreaded environments.`.  My post included the information about the WinForms timer to address your expectations of the accuracy of that timer.  Go back to your WinForms.Timer and see how it performs.

Comment: I've updated the code and created a progress bar to better represent what I'm trying to do.